# QT5.10 Cross Compilation on Raspberry PI

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi3

I use this manual to configure Ubuntu and RPI: http://ulasdikme.com/projects/raspberry/Qt_for_raspberrypi.php

I did all steps and everything seems to work.
I create blank QTQuick project in QTCreator and build it, everything is ok, no errors.
Then i copy executable file from Ubuntu to RPI and try to run, but i have error:

```
* failed to add service - already in use?
```

What it can be? maybe i need to copy somethig else?

If i create and compile progect nativly on RPI, using old version QT and QTcreator, it works well. But i need to use QT5.10 and newer for my project.

upd:

it crashes on function

```
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
```

if i have next code:

```
....

    printf("sig1");
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    printf("sig2");

....
```

i will have output:

```
sig1
* failed to add service - already in use?
```

i cant understand what is the problem?

Comment: Have you disabled the GUI on the pi and have booted into the command line? The EGLFS plugin does not work if a window manager is already running

Comment: how can i disable it? but i try next: copy file to rpi and run in on rpi natively. not from ubuntu.